# How to implement MD5 hashing in a user registration and login system?

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, md5

I am using PHP and Mysql. I want to know how to send password hashed using MD5 and want to check against it when the user tries to log in. I tried it, but it's not working properly. If anyone knows how to do it, please provide me the code.

Comment: Firstly, it's worth noting that MD5 in not encryption, it is a hashing or digest algorithm. When you say "send password encrypted in md5" do you mean in the user's request to server, or from your PHP file to MySQL?

Comment: Robus got it right, but if you want to save the Hazel you could use this PHP authentication class http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6174-PHP-Manage-registrations-and-authenticate-users.html

Comment: It may be me being picky about word choice, but where are you 'send'ing the hashed passwords?  Also, if you aren't using a salt, you should.  Also also, you might want to consider a more secure hashing function.

Comment: See also [SO 11911112](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191112/password-hashing-salt-and-storage-of-hashed-values) or [SO 1477944](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477944/user-login-with-a-single-query-and-per-user-password-salt), no doubt amongst many others.

Comment: @Slartibartfast: I think I'd cut Mujahid a bit of slack on 'send' as an issue with 'Use of English' which is probably not his mother tongue.  Agreed on the salt, though.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for improve my question

Comment: @Pablo Robus did *NOT* get it right. @Mujahid please don't roll your own for something like this. The comments indicate that `bcrypt` support is built into current PHP, and available via third party in older version. PLEASE use it.

Answer (score 5):

`md5` isn't very well suited to this purpose. Read [this article](http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html) to learn the hows and whys, but the short version is that you should use `bcrypt` instead. A quick Google shows that [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) claims to support `bcrypt`.

UPDATE: As @Dragontamer5788 points out in the comments, [`scrypt`](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html) is even better than `bcrypt` from a theoretical perspective. The author is good at crypto, but be aware that it's had less review and less real-world exposure than `bcrypt` at this point. I'd probably still choose it, but it's not as cut-and-dried as `bcrypt` over `md5`.

Comment: PHP 5.3+ supports BCrypt in its "crypt" functionality, while PHP 5.2 and earlier can get by with PHP Suhosin Patch (which implements BCrypt into PHP). Technically, "scrypt" is better than BCrypt because it places a memory constraint as well as a CPU constraint... but BCrypt is the best widely-spread password function at the moment. Might as well use it until good scrypt implementations exist. This answer needs more upvotes

Answer (score 0):

```
//Register:
$the_magical_salt = "everybody_is_obsessed_with_these_days$3^^2)(%=-"; // Even_though_md5_shouldnt_be_used
mysql_query('insert into users values (NULL,'.$filtered_username.','.md5($password.$the_magical_salt).');');
//Login:
$res = mysql_query('select password from users where username = '.$filtered_username);
$res = mysql_fetch_array($res);
if(md5($_POST['password'].$the_magical_salt) == $res[0]) echo "Yeah, you're welcome.";
else echo "Wrong password sugar";
```

There's not much to it other than using the md5() function twice.

Comment: You should use and store a salt - a random number - so as to prevent offline hashing attacks on the password.  Also, MD5 is barely adequate as a hashing mechanism; it would not be recommended by people like Bruce Schneier (and has not been recommended for a number of years now).

Comment: +1 because I've used something similar for wrong passwords. Oh the angry emails

Comment: @Robus - if you're going to bother with a salt, it should be cryptographically-unique per user and stored with the password in the database, not hardcoded in the PHP code.

Comment: @John Rasch
Wouldn't this make salts.. pointless? (I admit I'm not familiar with the topic as frameworks do this for me). I mean, wouldn't brute-forcing "password" and "password+salt", where salt is known, take the same amount of time?

Comment: @Robus - the purpose of a salt is to prevent against brute-forcing against a *database* of users, not one specific user's password. If the salt is the same for every user, it's much, much easier (i.e. possible) to perform a rainbow attack against the database. The threat of a rainbow attack is dramatically decreased (i.e. essentially no chance) if there had to be one generated for every user (defeating the purpose of generating it in the first place.)

Comment: Why are salts hardcoded? Salts need to be randomized to prevent the rainbow table. Now your opponent can just create a Rainbow Table with "everybody_is_obsessed_with_these_days$3^^2)(%=-" at the beginning and crush your password database. You need a cryptographically random salt to prevent the rainbow table.

Answer (score 0):

Without any more information it's going to be difficult to help you, but what I believe you want is [Digest Authentication](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2617.html).

Here is an example (specifically Example #7) from the PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Note that this type of authentication does not prevent against man-in-the-middle attacks. If, for example, someone is sniffing traffic on a victim's network, the attacker could simply replay the request with the digested username/password combination, and your PHP script would happily authenticate the attacker as the victim.

Comment: I want to save password from php textfield to mysql table. Its a normal user registration and login system. I saved it using encryption in db but when I use a select query to check whether both the login password and the password that user have already provided are same, it gives me nothing even though they're same. I am confused now,

Comment: OK Thanks everybody, I could do that, I saved it as MD5() and when I check the password I use same MD5() so it works fine :)